# How to call an axios request to an API URL with multi IP address in a VPS

Tags: node.js, express, axios, web-crawler

I have a VPS (have 3 IPs). I want to use it to crawl data and to avoid limit request. So I setup a nodejs app (expressJS) and use axios module to create request. But I don't know to use axios with each request, it use an different IP.

Any solution for the problem, thank you so much!